# On going back or re-opening the activity, ListView items gets repeated

Tags: android, listview

When I open a new activity from my listview activity and then go back to listview activity or if I reopen that same listview actvity , my listview items gets repeated.

```
public class PlaylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaylistBean> {

    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public final TextView name;
        public final ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namePlaylist);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagePlaylist);
        }
    }

    public PlaylistAdapter(Context context, List<PlaylistBean> items)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout_playlist, items);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_playlist, null);
        }

       final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        PlaylistBean playlistBean = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.name.setText(playlistBean.getName());
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(playlistBean.getImage());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is my code for PlaylistBean class

```
public class PlaylistBean implements Serializable {

    private int image;
    private String name;

    public PlaylistBean(int image, String name)
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my main activity

public class Playlist extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static List<PlaylistBean> items = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<PlaylistBean> myArrayAdapter;

 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);

        playlistListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playlistListView);
        myArrayAdapter = new PlaylistAdapter(Playlist.this, items);
         playlistListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

            createData();

}

 public void createData()
    {
        PlaylistBean bean1 = new PlaylistBean(R.drawable.popular_upload, "Popular Uploads");
    items.add(bean1);
}
```

}

Comment: A side note: You are not using the View Holder properly. Every time `getView()` is called a holder instance is created but it is never re used. And you have to post your activity code as well.

Comment: @MalithLakshan I have posted my activity code

Answer (score 2):

When your activity goes to background, you can clear your listview with below code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    yourListView.setListAdapter(null); //This clears the listview items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens.

- `List<PlaylistBean> items` is static.
- You use that list to create the `ListView`
- On the first run the `ListView` gets empty as there the `items.size()` is 0
- After you set the adapter `createData()` method is called which  fill list.
- This continues refilling the list.

How to over come this.
I hope that you want to display something in the list view at the first run and you want to keep the `items` list `static`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle sis){
    super.onCreate(sis);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);

    playlistListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playlistListView);
    //fill the list here.
    createData();
    myArrayAdapter = new PlaylistAdapter(Playlist.this, items);
    playlistListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
}
```

Then change your `createData()` method.

```
public static void createData(){
     //instatiate the list items here
     items=new ArrayList<>();
     PlaylistBean bean1 = new PlaylistBean(R.drawable.popular_upload, "Popular Uploads");
     items.add(bean1);
}
```

Comment: You are right. That createData() was causing the problem. Got it done